# Output the differences of two array values from a dropdown menu (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a database of arrays of nutritional facts for food items. All I'm looking to do is have the result of the selection of 2 items be the difference between the values of the first item and the second item. For example, if the first item is 72 calories and the other item is 50 calories, I want the output to say "22 more calories, x more grams of protein, y more grams of fat, etc". If the items are reversed, I want it to say 22 less calories, and so on.

This is the code I have so far. I'm able to output the values for each item, but haven't figured out how to output the differences:

```js
var stocks = [
  ["Beef (80/20) raw","oz",72,4.85,5.65,0,2.142,19,20,4],
  ["Beef (90/10) raw","oz",50,5.65,2.83,0,1.109,19,18,4]]
  
$(".selectStock").each(function (){
  for (var i = 0, len = stocks.length; i < len; i++) {
 $("<option>").html(stocks[i][0]).attr("value", i).appendTo(this);
}
});

function r2d (i) {
  return Math.round(i * 100) / 100
}

$(".selectStock").change(updateAmount);
$("#numberOfStocks").on('keyup', updateAmount);

function updateAmount() {
  $(".selectStock").each(function () {
    index = Number($(this).val());
    if (isNaN(index)) {
      return;
    }
    amt = Number($("#numberOfStocks").val());
    if (isNaN(amt) || amt == 0) {
      amt = stocks[index][9];
    }
    $(this).nextAll(".result:first").html("")
      .append((r2d(amt*stocks[index][2])).toLocaleString() + " calories<br />")
      .append((Math.round(stocks[index][3] * amt * 100)/100).toLocaleString() + " g of protein<br />")
    .append((Math.round(stocks[index][4] * amt * 1000)/1000).toLocaleString() + " g of fat <br />")
    .append((Math.round(stocks[index][5] * amt * 100)/100).toLocaleString() + " g of saturated fat <br />")
    .append((Math.round(stocks[index][6] * amt * 100)/100).toLocaleString() + " g of sugar <br />")
    .append((Math.round(stocks[index][7] * amt * 100)/100).toLocaleString() + " mg of sodium <br />")
    .append((Math.round(stocks[index][8] * amt * 100)/100).toLocaleString() + " mg of cholesterol <br />");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=10px, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <input value = "" type="text" id="numberOfStocks" />
  <div style="display:block;">
    <div class="side">
      <h2>ounce of: </h2>
    <select class="selectStock">
      <option>Pick a food!</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
      <h2>vs ounce of:</h2>
    <select class="selectStock">
      <option>Pick a food!</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Would appreciate guidance on this. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit with your code, and managed to come up with a solution. The logic I added is slightly convoluted, so if you have any questions please let me know. I may come back later and revise the code I've written to make it a bit clearer. I tried my best not to change your original `stocks` data structure, since it looks like you are receiving data in that format, but if you can change it I would suggest you do as there is nothing semantic about `stock[17]` or `stock[4]`.

```js
var stocks = [
  ["Beef (80/20) raw", "oz", 72, 4.85, 5.65, 0, 2.142, 19, 20, 1],
  ["Beef (90/10) raw", "oz", 50, 5.65, 2.83, 0, 1.109, 19, 18, 1],
  ["Milk", "fl oz", 10, 1.46, 0.45, 0, 1.944, 10, 13, 8] // Made up values
]

function Stock (data) {
  return {
    name: data[0],
    servingUnit: data[1],
    calories: [data[2], ''],
    protein: [data[3], 'g'],
    fat: [data[4], 'g'],
    saturatedFat: [data[5], 'g'],
    sugar: [data[6], 'g'],
    sodium: [data[7], 'mg'],
    cholesterol: [data[8], 'mg'],
    unitsPerServing: data[data.length - 1]
  }
}

stocks = stocks.map(Stock)

var $selects = $('.selectStock')
var $quantity = $('#numberOfStocks')
var $comparisonResult = $('.comparison .result')

$selects.each(function() {
  $(this).append(stocks.map(function(stock, i) {
    return new Option(stock.name, i)
  }))
})

function format(data, multiplier, digits) {
  data = data.slice()
  data[0] = (+(data[0] * multiplier).toFixed(digits)).toLocaleString()
  return data.join(' ')
}

function stockFacts(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.calories, quantity, 2) + ' calories<br>' +
    format(stock.protein, quantity, 2) + ' of protein<br>' +
    format(stock.fat, quantity, 3) + ' of fat<br>' +
    format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2) + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
    format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2) + ' of sugar<br>' +
    format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2) + ' of sodium<br>' +
    format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2) + ' of cholesterol<br>'
  ]
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}

function updateAmount() {
  var quantity = +$quantity.val() 
    
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $result = $(this).nextAll('.result').empty()
    var $amount = $(this).prev().find('.servingUnit').empty()
    var stock = getStock(this)
    if (!stock) return
    var amount = quantity * stock.unitsPerServing
    
    $amount.text(' (' + amount + ' ' + stock.servingUnit + ')')
    
    $result.html(stockFacts(stock, amount))
  })
  
  var selected = [].map.call($selects, getStock)
  $comparisonResult.empty()
  if (!selected[0] || !selected[1]) return
  var diff = {}
  Object.keys(selected[0]).forEach(function (k) {
    if (/^(name|servingUnit|unitsPerServing)$/.test(k)) return
    var first = selected[0][k].slice()
    var second = selected[1][k].slice()
    first[0] *= selected[0].unitsPerServing
    second[0] *= selected[1].unitsPerServing
    diff[k] = [Math.abs(first[0] - second[0]), first[1], first[0] > second[0] ? 'more' : 'less']
  })
  $comparisonResult.html(stockFacts(diff, quantity))
}
```

```css
.side,
.comparison {
  width: 33.333%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=10px, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <label>
    Servings:
    <input type="number" id="numberOfStocks" value="1" min="0" />
  </label>

  <div>
    <div class="side">
      <h2>First Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
      <select class="selectStock">
        <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
      <h2>Second Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
      <select class="selectStock">
        <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="comparison">
      <h2>Comparison:</h2>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is awesome- thanks a bunch! I'm basically importing this from CSV so I am able to convert to JSON objects if that's easier. stocks[17] is supposed to be the serving amount (4 means 4 oz for example) and I need it to be the automatic value put in the text box. Do you know how I'd be able to do this? Also another thing is that I need to have the serving unit (oz for example) show up in Quantity (oz) so that it's dynamic if the unit is in grams, fl oz, liters, etc. Do you know how I'd be able to do this as well? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Yes, I should be able to do this. I'm not able to edit my answer at the moment, but give me an hour or two and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I still don't see how what `stocks[17]` is supposed to get . . . could you give me the complete CSV? I did clean up the code a bit and add dynamic units; let me know whether that works as you had hoped. I will clean it up a little more later when I can find the time :)

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! stocks[17] is in my original data, but I have it condensed in this example- it is stocks[9] in the sample array. It is the amount of units that constitute a serving (for example a serving of milk is 8 fl oz so stocks[9] for milk is 8). I'd like the default output when selecting a food to be the serving amount- so stocks[9] * 1 unit of food. Later on I'd also want to have an option where First Item and Second Item are to be able to change the units (oz to pounds/grams and fl oz to liters/gallons).  Does this make sense? Would really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: I did the first part, I think, let me know if the math makes sense. I think this is as far as your original question went; I will leave the unit conversion as an exercise to you and if you run into any new problems feel free to post an additional question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go work on that. I also need to implement code that changes the color of the values in "Converted" to green if it is "more" and red if it is "less". Do you know how to go about doing this? Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, hope things are well. I tried formatting the code to allow units and have 2 inputs for amounts instead of 1, and now my code is spitting out random numbers. Would really appreciate help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439763/javascript-calculations-are-way-off-trying-to-output-differences-of-arrays-from

Answer (score 1):

I made a simplified version of your problem here on JS fiddle, if the formatting/link is wrong here a mod can correct:

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/xnymo46d/17/ JS Fiddle code

```
// Create food objects to hold info about the food
var food = [];
food[0] = { name: "Beef", calories:"70", protein:"25" }
food[1] = { name: "Chicken", calories:"80", protein:"30" }
food[2] = { name: "Steak", calories:"150", protein:"20" }

// Store food in dropdowns on load
for (i = 0; i < food.length; ++i) 
    $("select[name='food[]']").append('<option value="' + i + '">' + food[i].name + '</option>');

// Call a function to calculate differences when options are changed
$('select').on('change', function() {
  getDifference();
})

function getDifference()
{
  // Get the selected food options
  var foodOptions = $("select[name='food[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
  var calories = [];
  var protein = [];

  for (i = 0; i < foodOptions.length; ++i)
  {
    var thisIndex = $("select[name='food[]']").eq(i).val();
        calories[i] = food[thisIndex].calories;
    protein[i] = food[thisIndex].protein;
  }

  // calculate difference between calories
  var differenceCalories = calories[0] - calories[1];
  var differenceProtein = protein[0] - protein[1];

    if (!differenceCalories)
    $("#result-calories").html('The calories are the same between your selected food items');
  else if (differenceCalories > 0)
    $("#result-calories").html('There are ' + differenceCalories + ' more calories in your first selection than second');
  else
    $("#result-calories").html('There are ' + (differenceCalories * -1) + ' less calories in your second selection than first');

        if (!differenceProtein)
    $("#result-protein").html('The protein is the same between your selected food items');
  else if (differenceProtein > 0)
    $("#result-protein").html('There are ' + differenceProtein + ' more grams of protein in your first selection than second');
  else
    $("#result-protein").html('There are ' + (differenceProtein * -1) + ' less grams of protein in your second selection than first');
}
```

I think your code would be easier to interpret/work with if you made your food items into JS **objects** similar to what I did. That way, you can give identifiers to each food item (eg. calories, protein, etc.). Because right now, that code you have for the the stocks (food) is VERY confusing; you have all these numbers and don't know what they represent (I'm assuming other factors including fat, sodium, carbs, etc.). Maybe you do, but I don't, and even for your sake it looks hard/confusing to work with. After creating an array of objects, I then loop through all of them and append t hem to the dropdowns, similar to how you did.
I then made a function to loop through all the dropdown selections when a dropdown is changed, loading their selected value and collected the food item selected. (you could even tie it to a button or something). I then stored the calories and proteins in a different array and compared the two. This step could be done any way you want; you could even just collect both food objects.

There are tons of different ways you can go about this problem. This is rough the way I would do it; you have a more efficient/optimized way to store the data about the food (stock), and you have a way to dynamically load through the dropdowns without writing redundant code. The way I also did this, you could use an unlimited amount of dropdowns as well (like if you wanted to compare 4, 6, or even 100 different food items). Of course, you would have to modify the way you are calculating the differences then. Anyway, hope that helps steer you in the right direction.